# How to return a empty result when using FileStreamResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My images are served from a controller action that returns FileStreamResult.

I load the image based on a id that is passed via a image tag:

```
<img src="Image/Get/234" />
```

My code is:

```
 public FileResult Get(int id)
            {
                File file = // get file

                if (file != null)
                {
                    ...
                    ...
                    return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg");
                }
                return new FileStreamResult(null, null);
            }
```

Say the id passed doesn't map to a file, how can I return a empty image or is passing null like I am doing fine?

Actually if I pass in a wrong id, I get:

```
Value cannot be null or empty.
```

I don't want to return an error, just silenty ignore it somehow like return a blank image etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a image by code or you could pass a placeholder image that you have in a hardcoded path. It's depend how intelligent the client/UI is, could it handle `null` or in what context should it be displayed?